# AnyLogic - Unable to execute user action: SVG element with id 1509 not found, possibly has been deleted already

Tags: svg, anylogic

`Unable to execute user action: SVG element with id 1509 not found, possibly has been deleted already`

`Unable to execute user action: SVG element with id 1511 not found, possibly has been deleted already`

This is not an error as my model is still able to run. But once in a while I do receive this prompt in the console. What does this mean and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

It is 100% irrelevant and is caused by how AnyLogic draws/hides visual shapes while you navigate through the model.

No need to trying to get rid of it, you can completely ignore it :)